# Add lower() to a field in addIndex() in sequelize migration

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

To create a unique index in sequelize migrations we can do something like below,

```
 await queryInterface.addIndex(SCHOOL_TABLE, {
        fields: ['name', 'school_id'],
        unique: true,
        name: SCHOOL_NAME_ID_UNIQUE_INDEX,
        where: {
          is_deleted: false
        },
        transaction,
      })
```

The problem is It allows duplicates due to case senstivity.

In the doc [here](https://sequelize.org/v4/class/lib/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-addIndex), It is mentioned that `fields` should be `an array of attributes`.

How can I apply `lower()` to `name` field so that It can become case insensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a workaround for now, using raw query. I don't think `addIndex()` supports using functions on `fields`.

```
await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`CREATE  UNIQUE INDEX  IF NOT EXISTS ${SCHOOL_NAME_ID_UNIQUE_INDEX} 
        ON ${SCHEMA}.schools USING btree (lower(name), school_id) where is_deleted = false;
        `, { transaction});
```